# Why do I get ErrorValue while constructing my dict

Tags: python

```
pkwargs = dict(("tickNum", tickNum), **kwargs)
```

Here, I add a key-value pair in a tuple to a list of key-value pairs and output it as a new dict.
And it raises `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required`.

```
pkwargs = dict(("tickNum", tickNum), kwargs)
```

Here I add the same key-value pair to a dict than output it as a new dict.
And it raises `TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`.

I don't understand why.... Nor how I can fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
pkwargs = dict(("tickNum", tickNum), **kwargs)
```

The first argument needs to be an iterable of pairs. Since you gave a pair directly it interprets that as an iterable and `"tickNum"` as a pair, which has 7 elements (characters), not 2. Do this:

```
pkwargs = dict([("tickNum", tickNum)], **kwargs)
```

Or better yet:

```
pkwargs = dict(tickNum=tickNum, **kwargs)
```

Here `tickNum` becomes one of the keyword arguments along with the rest of `kwargs`.